# Access Compile Error on ADO recordset open - possible reference issue?

Tags: ms-access, reference, ado

As a bit of background we are a small Access software house with 10 + years of working with over 150 Customer sites.  We have 5 different apps.   Our main product has over 30,000 lines of vba and about 400 forms and reports.  I am telling you this background as we think we know our vba and access. We normally work in Access 2003, but compile and distribute in Access 2k, Occasionally we will work in Access 2002 , 2007 and 2010.

We have run into a problem where in the last week or so some (not all) of our applications will not allow us to compile on some machines.  Last week we had a problem with one windows7 box where Access 2003 was regularly crashing (that seemed to rectify itself on a compile on an XP machine and amove to worko solely in Access 2k), this week a second win 7 box is having problems with a specific app (will not compile - error on opening an ADO recordset).  This seems to have started after an install of Access 2010. This seems now to have "spread" to other machines.

We think its most likely an ADO reference issue but it is weird as other apps as other apps with the same references on the same PC and the same lines of code complile OK.

What we have tried so far, all machines are up to date with latest MS patches. We have uninstalled and reinstalled the various versions of access.  It seems to be worse (and starts on) Win 7 but we now have a version that will not complile on XP Pro or Vista.  Some of these machines we have been using for 4 or 5 years and have had no such issues.  Thanks in anticipation of your feedback.

Comment: See if this helps: http://allenbrowne.com/bug-17.html

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like the problems caused by compiling on Windows 7 64-bit with SP1 installed. This causes the code to not be runnable on machines without SP1 of 64-bit Windows.

The solution is to compile on pre-SP1 installations of Windows 7 64-bit.

And, yes, this is a terrible, terrible problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer - we don't believe this is patch level as we don't upgrade machines all at the same time - it may have something to do with Access 2010 and an associated reference to ADO although we have not been able to prove that.

Anyway for anyone else that has this problem in the future we have solved the problem by taking another (completely different) application that compiles correctly, deleting all the objects (forms, reports etc) and copying across all the objects from the one that did not compile to the (now empty) application.  A recompile now works fine thankfully.

Comment: This is a reply to my comment, and should be posted there, instead of as an answer. What you describe sounds EXACTLY like the SP1 issue, because it was a reference to ADO that caused the problem. The two solutions offered by MS are to compile on a machine that does not have SP1, or to use ADO with late binding.